# Copy Mysql table to another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables spider.expedient and spider 367.expedient, I want to copy the data from the spider.expedient table to the spider_367.expedient table daily, respecting the data from the previous day and ignoring possible duplicates.

I have run this query but it gives me error by duplicates. Is the correct way to achieve this?

```
INSERT INTO spider_367.expedient SELECT * FROM spider.expedient
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches that generally work well.

**Option 1:** add a clause to make an ineffectual change when duplicates are found:

```
INSERT INTO spider_367.expedient
SELECT * FROM spider.expedient
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE x=x
```

Replace `x` with one of your field names.

**Option 2:** do a left join and only insert the records that don't match

```
INSERT INTO spider_367.expedient
SELECT x1.* FROM spider.expedient x1
LEFT JOIN spider_367.expedient x2 ON x1.id = x2.id
WHERE x2.id IS NULL
```

Replace `x1.id` and `x2.id` with your key fields.

Comment: or You can use INSERT IGNORE (because in question was - ignore duplicates)

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` can ignore other problems too, I don't recommend it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update#548570.

Comment: Yes, it can ... but it more close to the question ;), all what You suggest - correct, but author just want ignore duplicates ... so ...

Answer (score 0):

In a similar vein, "Normalization" involves creating new rows, while not bothering with existing rows.  I think the `INSERT..SELECT` process is optimal.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Hosts (host_name)
    SELECT DISTINCT s.host_name
        FROM Staging AS s
        LEFT JOIN Hosts AS n  ON n.host_name = s.host_name
        WHERE n.host_id IS NULL;
```

More discussion [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization) (and explanation of context for this snippet).